# Can't get console logging to work in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, console, .net-core

I have the following code:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

Configuration = builder.Build();
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                                                .AddConsole()
                                                .AddDebug())
    .AddSingleton<IEngine, Engine>()
    .BuildServiceProvider();
var engine = serviceProvider.GetService<IEngine>();
await engine.RunAsync();
```

And

```
public class Engine : IEngine
{
    private readonly ILogger<Engine> logger;

    public Engine(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Engine>();
    }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        logger.LogError("Test");
        logger.LogTrace("Starting engine!");
    }
}
```

Then i have the following configuration

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But nothing is logged to the console, but i do get output in the debug log, so what am i missing?

I have verified that it finds the config file so that is not the issue!

Answer (score 3):

Well it seems .net core 2.0 has a delay before printing to the console.

So it was working i just wasn't waiting for it to flush!

Comment: How did you wait?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling a Thread.Sleep and waiting for the logger to finish, if you retain an instance of the logger, you can execute:

> logger.Dispose()

to force the logger to flush (output) its cache before the application closes.

If the logger is tied to an IContainer or ServiceProvider, you should be able to Dispose() on those to achieve the same effect.

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file/issues/16